# Recursive elimination of minimum number in a array

Tags: matlab, signals

I have an array consisting of 4 groups:

```
A=[1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4]
```

Here "1" appears six times, "2" four times, "3" twice and "4" once.
In the first iteration, I should find the number that appears least number of times (in this case 4) and replace it with the next least appearing number (i.e replace 4 with 3). Then in the second iteration, the least appearing number is 3 so i should replace it with 2.

Can someone please help with a simple code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to count repeating elements in an array, you can use [`hist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) of the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) elements to do that. Here's a sketch:

```
values = unique(A);
while 1
    counts = hist(A, values);
    % work only with values that has count > 0
    sel = counts == 0;
    counts(sel) = inf;
    if sum(~sel) < 2
        % stop - you reached the last unique value
        break
    end
    [mc, mi] = min(counts); % found value with minimal number of occurences
    mv = values(mi); % the value to be eliminated
    counts(mi) = inf;
    [mc2, mi2] = min(counts); % find second min 
    A(A==mv) = values(mi2) % replace
end
```

Comment: Hi Shai, Thank you. I tried your code but unfortunately it is not working. Can you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Rachel please try now.

Comment: @Rachel but you can see how `A` is updated from one iteration  to the other. it is up to you to decide how you save these intermediate results.